# Writing CSV with RUBY and Removing double spacing

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

I'm reading in text files and writing to CSV. However, the CSV is writing lines every other row. I've tried changing options,gsub, chomp - but it seams like there are carriage return line that I'm not seeing.

```
#make CSV 
#read text file and write contents to it

File.open(new_csv_path, headers: true, write_headers: true) do |csv|

  #make headers
  if csv.tell = 0
    csv << "first_column, second_column, third_columnn\n"
  end

  File.foreach(text_file) do |text|
    csv << text
  end
end
```

## file.txt looks like this:

```
What type of loan are you currently in? (VA, FHA, Conventional)

What is your current interest rate? 6.25

Who is your current lender?

Do you occupy the home as your primary residence?
```

## output.csv LOOKS LIKE THIS:

```
What type of loan are you currently in? (VA, FHA, Conventional)
                                             #i need to delete this line
What is your current interest rate? 6.25

Who is your current lender?

Do you occupy the home as your primary residence?
```

As you can see it prints but there's an extra line. How do I delete line? I've read other posts but I haven't seen one dealing with this the double spacing problem. If I missed please send me the discussion thread. Thanks

Comment: the data I'm reading is also double spaced but that shouldn't make a difference - I could still strip out the lines when writing to csv.

Comment: Is that really the code?   you do |text| but csv << line  ?

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: `if csv.tell = 0` has smell to it. Do you really intend to assign `0` to `csv.tell` in a conditional test?

Comment: yes line is supposed to be text. I fixed. I put put the sample input as well. I've tried to strip (i.e. text.strip) but it puts all lines in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible error

```
  File.foreach(text_file) do |text|
    csv << line   <-------- shouldn't this be |text|
  end
```

to make it consistent, you can `chomp` or `strip` the newlines, then add accordingly

Comment: I'm assuming they typed a dumbed down version for simplicity/confidentiality and just made a mental error.

Comment: Well, it's not really an answer to the question. They've proven they gets some sort of output so it's obviously not the problem.

Comment: Even if its not an answer, its still "possible", without OP clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

`csv << line.strip`

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-strip